# How to fix this error? DataReader must be closed first

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

What im trying to do is, when you delete a record in the sql-server database it will first check if the quantity is greater than zero, if it is then it will not delete the record. I think its working now but I keep getting this error "DataReader must be closed first" no matter what I do. any help would be appreciated.

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-MQKIBSK\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=inventory2;Integrated Security=True");
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Quantity FROM Items WHERE (Barcode  = '" + dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value + "')", cn);
        SqlDataReader quantityRdr = null;
        quantityRdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (quantityRdr.Read())
        {
            string squantity = quantityRdr["Quantity"].ToString();
            int x = Int32.Parse(squantity);
            if (x > 0)

            {
                MessageBox.Show("You can't delete this record");

            }
            else
            {            
                DialogResult r = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this record?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (r == DialogResult.Yes)
                {

                    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(@"DELETE FROM Items where (Barcode  = '" + dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value + "')", cn);
                    MessageBox.Show("Item deleted!");
                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    fill();                     
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("invalid");
                }
            }



        }
```

Comment: On what line do you get the error? And on another note, why don't you close the DataReader first?

Comment: on the cmd1.executenonquery(); line. but its okay now thanks to the answer below

Comment: What a wonderful schema for Sql Injection. I don't even need to know the column's name. It is enough to type _' OR 1=1' --_ Search about Sql Injection as soon as possible

Comment: I will sir ty. ill use parameters when its all finish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below tag in your connection string.

```
"MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the different sql connection to solve this problem.